# ImageMagick cannot use identify on remote image if it contains a port number

Tags: command-line, php, encoding, url, imagemagick

I am having trouble using exec identify on a remote image with imagemagick if the url contains a port number. So the url appears like this: http://isite.com:81/image.jpg If I remove the :81 it works. What can I do? Either fixing this issue with imagemagick or removing the port number is fine. I tried using PHP's parse_url function to remove the port, however I cannot reconstruct the url afterwards because http_build_url() function is not available on my server and I cannot install it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using at least this version:  ImageMagick 6.6.3-1 2010-07-26 Q16

This is the version I have on one of my computers, and if I specify TCP port 80 (the default anyway) it works just fine.

Also, the site you referenced is down right now, so make sure that it's up and running before you attempt this again (if it was an example, then you should have used the RFC-compliant "www.example.com" to make this clear).

Comment: Will this url work for you? http://img.wallpaperstock.net:81/jeep-in-desert-wallpapers_11419_1600x1200.jpg

Comment: I am using ImageMagick 6.6.7-7 2011-02-19 Q16

Comment: When using the "identify.exe http://img.wallpaperstock.net:81/jeep-in-desert-wallpapers_11419_1600x1200.jpg" command I got this result (that's an amazing and beautiful picture, by the way):  
http://img.wallpaperstock.net:81/jeep-in-desert-wallpapers_11419_1600x1200.jpg=>C:/Users/Randolf/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-8sbsdSIB JPEG 1600x1200 1600x1200+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 220KB 0.000u 0:00.002

Comment: So if you're running this straight from the command-line, it should work for you.  From within PHP, however, may be a different matter if PHP is altering your command before shelling out to execute it.